# Does SpriteKit and SceneKit allow access to iOS microphone input during game play?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, core-audio

I am making a simple sprite kit game that needs an audio input from the microphone for voice commands. I have already created a simple game and I have already created a separate app that if you speak a word it detects and it displays on the screen using cmu-sphinx/pocketsphinx (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).

I was using Novocaine (https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) because I have used this library numerous times and had great success with it in other projects in the past, but whenever I initiate the Novocaine object in the game, my app crashes with an exception.

So I figured that since I was using a wrapper library it must have been some deprecated functions that were not supported any more, so I did some more research. I came across Apple's demo app AurioTouch (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html). After playing around with that sample app, I was able to narrow down the classes that I needed to get the raw input values, which was primarily the AudioController class. So I imported over the AudioController class and its necessary components and was able to build it. Fortunately, the example had proper exception handling so I was able to see where it was failing. The exception was caused by this line:

`AudioUnitInitialize(_rioUnit)`

I was beginning to suspect that trying to access the microphone in a SpriteKit/SceneKit environment was causing the issue. I've also tried the same steps mentioned above in brand new SpriteKit and SceneKit projects and did not resolve the issue. So I am wondering if it is anyway possible for you to give real time microphone input within a SpriteKit/SceneKit project.

Comment: I don't think they're interconnected. Hard to answer your question w/o knowing what the exception is.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I know they do have some form of access to the audio engine, but looking at those documentation, it didnt seem like there was any sort of connection between the CoreAudio and the 2 different kits. The full line is this `XThrowIfError(AudioUnitInitialize(_rioUnit), "couldn't initialize AURemoteIO instance");`

Comment: You could moving your problem code on it's own test app to see if it works in isolation. Otherwise you'll have to use the debugger. What is _rioUnit set to? Anything in your console? (You can also check your syslog)

Comment: So after much debugging, I got the app to run in the iOS simulator, but when I try to run it on an actual device the exception happens in that same place. I think this has to do with the app asking for permission to use your microphone. But I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), possibly as a GitHub project, along with the relevant parts of code (not just one line!) in your question, and the details of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in the iOS Settings app under Privacy : Microphone, where you have to switch on permission for an app to use the device's microphone.  The AVAudioSession requestRecordPermission API can help check this permission setting.

There are also some AVAudioSession categories that should be set and activated to use the microphone.  The use of SpriteKit and SceneKit does not interfere with these settings.

Comment: [I think it might be.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH1-SW109)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was a combination of privacy settings and since I was using some deprecated core audio functions, I tried to update some of the calls using the AVAudioSession functions, but I did not fully understand some of the function calls. I had revert back to all the deprecated functions and it launched fine.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10 Apple is extending the scope of privacy control. You have to declare in Info.plist file access of any private data.

Goto Info.Plist file and added the privacy key according to your requirement.

Microphone :
Key      :  Privacy - Microphone Usage Description
Value    :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) allow microphone use to give audio input for voice commands.